# Multivariate interpolation in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I need to do multivariate interpolation in Scala. I am using LinearInterpolator of breeze.interpolation but cannot find a way to pass a matrix. I wonder if anyone know if it's possible?

This is what I've tried:

```
import breeze.interpolation.LinearInterpolator 
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, DenseVector} 
val dm = DenseMatrix(
  Array(1.2, 2.4, 6.8), 
  Array(1.5, 2.6, 6.1), 
  Array(1.3, 2.9, 6.8), 
  Array(1.7, 2.2, 6.2), 
  Array(1.1, 2.8, 6.8), 
  Array(1.7, 2.1, 6.9)
) 
val dv = DenseVector(2.2, 3.1, 5.2, 1.8, 4.4, 7, 2)   
LinearInterpolator(dm, dv)
```

It does not run because `Linearinterpolator()` does not seem to allow `DenseMatrix`. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share your attempts so far, and eventually provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: I would like to implement the following code (below) but it does not run because Linearinterpolator() does not seem allow DenseMatrix. Many thanks in advance!           import breeze.interpolation.LinearInterpolator
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, DenseVector}

val dm = DenseMatrix(Array(1.2, 2.4, 6.8), Array(1.5, 2.6, 6.1), Array(1.3, 2.9, 6.8), Array(1.7, 2.2, 6.2), Array(1.1, 2.8, 6.8), Array(1.7, 2.1, 6.9))
val dv = DenseVector(2.2, 3.1, 5.2, 1.8, 4.4, 7,2)

LinearInterpolator(dm, dv)

Comment: Please don't post walls of code in the comment section. If you want to update your question, use the little gray 'edit' button.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Interpolation) it may be impossible:

> breeze.interpolation module currently supports interpolation facilities for data in one dimension (univariate interpolation)

and looking at the types of [attributes of the `LinearInterpolator`](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/interpolation/LinearInterpolator.scala) class you can see you need to pass `Vector`, and [`DenseMatrix`](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/DenseMatrix.scala) is not a `Vector`.

Comment: @michaJIS That's what it is written in the documentation but it does not work.

Comment: @zmicer - in the documentation it is written that it does NOT support multivariate interpolation. Types say the same thing.